# :hover usage in html and css

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me where I can use `:hover`? 
In the last CSS line it's `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content` which gets me a dropdown menu when I hover on dropdown element.

However, if I use `.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content` instead, no dropdown menu is displayed. Why is that?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

Comment: `.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content` would target a child element—the link has no children elements. `. dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content` will target the direct sibling and is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, The dropdown menu is a part of a list element.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
</li>
```

Your class "dropbtn" is a class which is applied for an anchor link you've placed. So that's why when you use the code

```
.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
```

}

It does not make sense, because the div with class "dropdown-content" is not a child of the element which contains the class "dropbtn" - which is a simple anchor element.

however, The code:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

works becausue the class "dropdown" is the class of the parent element, which is the list element and then under it, we have the div with class "dropdown-content".

That's how CSS works and hope it makes sense.